# zsh vcs_info per repo configuration

Tags: git, version-control, zsh

Im trying to disable check-for-changes style in specyfic huge repository due to poor performance. Im trying to this:

```
zstyle :vcs_info:git:* check-for-changes true
zstyle :vcs_info:git:*:huge_repo1 check-for-changes false
zstyle :vcs_info:git:*:huge_repo2 check-for-changes false
```

but it doesn't work, while this:

```
zstyle :vcs_info:git:*:huge_repo1 formats foo
```

replaces format as intended
Is there any way to disable `check-for-changes` for specific repo properly?

Comment: I'm also confused by this. Based on [the documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#Version-Control-Information), it looks like you should be able to use `repo-root-name` (ctrl+f the docs for that string). This suggests what you've shown should work. Do you really need the more complicated answer shown below? Does it only work for some parameters, like `formats` but not `check-for-changes`?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of per-directory vcs_info configuration:
https://github.com/johan/zsh/blob/master/Misc/vcs_info-examples#L88-L102

```
zstyle -e ':vcs_info:git:*' \
    check-for-changes 'estyle-cfc && reply=( true ) || reply=( false )'

function estyle-cfc() {
    local d
    local -a cfc_dirs
    cfc_dirs=(
        ${HOME}/src/code/*(/)
    )

    for d in ${cfc_dirs}; do
        d=${d%/##}
        [[ $PWD == $d(|/*) ]] && return 0
    done
    return 1
}
```